# jqgrid drag line issue

Tags: jqgrid, resize

everyone, I used jQgrid which is amazing in my project and found one issue on draging the column to resize in Chrome(Version 25.0.1337.0), it was like the drag line deviating from the header line when I was trying to resize the column, below is the screenshot
[image]

the red line is the drag line, and the blue one is the header column bar, more strange  about that is when I moved mouse to the drag place which was exactly the blue column bar and begun to drag, the mouse icon which should like([image])disappered in Chrome.

But it behaved cool in Firefox and IE, here's the screenshot(in Firefox)
[image]

how to fix this in Chrome? my jqgrid version is 4.4.4

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution which is not elegant, but behave what I want in IE8, Chrome v25, firefox v3.6, this could just be a crude fix!!
in  getOffset  method

```
getOffset = function (iCol) {             
      var i, ret = [0], brd1 = $.jgrid.cell_width ? 0 : ts.p.cellLayout;
```

> if(/chrome/i.test(navigator.userAgent)) brd1 = 5;//this could temporarily fix in chrome

```
         for(i=0;i<=iCol;i++){
            if(ts.p.colModel[i].hidden === false ) {
                ret[0] += ts.p.colModel[i].width+brd1;
            }
        }
        if(ts.p.direction=="rtl") {   ret[0] = ts.p.width - ret[0]; }
        ret[0] -= ts.grid.bDiv.scrollLeft;
        ret.push($(ts.grid.hDiv).position().top);
        ret.push($(ts.grid.bDiv).offset().top - $(ts.grid.hDiv).offset().top + $(ts.grid.bDiv).height());
        return ret;
    }
```

as you can see, I explicitly assign brd1 = 5..because in chrome  $.jqgrid.cell_width return true, while in firefox/IE it returns false

Comment: Are you overriding a getOffset method in jqGrid? I failed to find it in the definitions in jqgrid wiki. Is it there?

Comment: And what's grid and hDiv, bDiv? I assume grid is the grid table?